# crear objetos con un valor que aumente(JAVA)

Tags: java, poo

como están?, me explico tengo un programa que crea animales, la clase tiene sus métodos, variables,etc, y lo que quiero hacer es crear objetos con nombres iguales pero que un numero en su instancia cambie por ejemplo:

```
int cantidad = 2;
for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
Animal perro+i = new Animal("perro"+Integer.toString(i));
}
```

que seria lo mismo que esto:

```
Animal perro0 = new Animal("perro0");
Animal perro1 = new Animal("perro1");
Animal perro2 = new Animal("perro2");
```

En mi mente se vería así, pero la instancia(no se si se dice así) "perro+i" no sirve, entonces no se como se puede hacer algo que me cree los hijos de esa forma, ya que esto me ahorraría demasiado trabajo, porque debo tener 6 especies distintas y cada una con cantidades distintas de creación, espero haberme explicado bien y muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: creo que no necesitas nada de eso... porque os queres indexar??? cada instancia es un anima ldiferente por mas que tenga el mismo nombre

Comment: Lo que vos queres es un array de objetos ;)... esa es la forma de no tener mil variables iguales

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La única forma que tienes de conseguir esto creo que es así

```
int cantidad = 2;
List<Animal> perros = new ArrayList<Animal>();
for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
    perros.add(new Animal("perro"+i));
}
```

Y después puedes acceder a tus perros así

```
perros.get(n)
```

También podrías usar un array pero tendría un length fijo

Comment: esta perfecto esto, pero no deberia ser perro0... deberia ser perro, y llegado el caso la clase deberia tener un indice..

Comment: perro0 que sería? El nombre del perro?

Comment: Eso parece... por eso te digo de aclarar esa parte... el los queria nombrar como las variables...

Comment: No te había entendido antes. Si lo que el quiere es que el perro se llame igual que la variable, no le queda otra que hacerlo manualmente uno a uno. Aunque yo no le vería mucho sentido.

Comment: No se si te respondo por aquí o por otro lado, funciono a la perfección, y si mi intención era esa, hacer de las instancias algo simple y fácil de crear, ya que la variable cantidad me la va  a dar un archivo que se va a poder modificar de otro parte, junto con los otros parámetros de la clase, muchas gracias por su ayuda <3333